# Make a div always 100% of the viewport

Tags: html, css

Basically i have a sidecolumn and a main column. The side column holds some navigation icons, and the main will have an iframe.

Almost 90% of the time the iframe content will be around 2000px in height. The problem is that having my sidebar absolutely positioned to the side causes the `min-height: 100%;` to only take into account the viewport height when you load the page.

When you scroll down the page to see all of the main content, once you hit the end of the sidebar, it just cuts off. This looks horrible, and i want to know if there is a **PURE CSS** solution to the problem i am getting? I could just make a background image that has the dark grey bar and `repeat-y`, however i just wanted to see if there is any other solutions.

The reason i don't want to use `position: fixed;` is that sometimes that sidebar menu height will change, meaning i might need a user to be able to use the pagescroll to see the other options.

I've made a jsfiddle to help demonstrate my point, which can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/kKjBY/1/

My HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="main_content" class="large">
            <p>Main content</p>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul class="sidebar_nav">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>8</li>
                <li>9</li>
                <li>0</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 60px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #323232;
  color: #fff;
}
#main_content{
    padding-left: 80px;    
    height: 3000px; /* stricly to demonstrate */
}
#sidebar ul{ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#sidebar li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to the wrapper div and `bottom:0;` to the sidebar.

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W725c/1/

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe i missed this one.. I feel pretty stupid. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The div needs to be

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

It will then stay within the viewport's dimensions and "travel" with the scrollbar.

I`enter code here it will only cover the entire viewport if  is styled to

margin: 0;
padding: 0;